# Extra empty row in my table

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have modified my below code so many ways, but somehow an extra empty line always appear at the end of table. What is wrong with my logic ?

```
   <% if !@inviteList.empty? %>
     <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
       <tr style="color:white; background-color:teal">
         <th> Dated </th>
         <th> Email </th>
         <th> Acceptance </th>
       </tr>
       <% @inviteList.each do |f| %>
         <tr>
           <td> <%= f.created_at %> </td> 
           <td><%= f.email %> </td>
           <td> <%= link_to 'Yes', '#', class: "label label-info" %>  </td>
         </tr>
       <%end%>
     </table>
   <%else%>
     <h5 style="text-align:center"> No Invites </h5>
   <%end%>
```

Comment: Side note: You can change `!@inviteList.empty?` to `@inviteList.present?`. Just a cleaner way of doing things.

Comment: Have you compared `@inviteList.count` and the number of rows that have content?

Comment: Also, what happens when you remove the the first `tr` with the titles for each column? Probably not the issue but you never know.

Comment: thanks @jason328 ..for the suggestion...and removing by first <tr> still shows extra empty line

Comment: @Skram counts are same ...but extra empty line pops up

Comment: @Rahul what about when you view the HTML source versus looking in the DOM? Maybe some JS is to blame?

Comment: @Skram looking at DOM, it is justing showing an empty row ..with empty columns ..guessing something wrong with logic ? where its creating an extra row unnecessarily

Comment: Just in case, add the `thead` and `tbody` tag.